# issue with Java.lang.Cloneable interface guidelines

Tags: java, clone

As per `java.lang.Cloneable` interface:

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) for the `Cloneable` says -

> Note that this interface does not contain the clone method. Therefore, it is not possible to clone an object merely by virtue of the fact that it implements this interface. Even if the clone method is invoked reflectively, there is no guarantee that it will succeed.

But the following code is working correctly. It is not giving any error when I call `ex1.clone`.

```
package com.sriPushpa.thread;

public class exceptionHandling implements Cloneable {
    int a = 10;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        exceptionHandling ex1 = new exceptionHandling();
        exceptionHandling ex2 = null;
        try {
            ex2 = (exceptionHandling) ex1.clone();

        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    }

}
```

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes that's right, deleted my comment and +1.

Comment: Thanks to all .Now I have understood the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clone()` method is implemented by `java.lang.Object`, as a protected method. Your code works because you're calling the `clone()` method from the same class as the one you clone.

If you want your object to be cloneable, you should override the `clone()` method and make it public:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
```

Note that the doc doesn't say that implementing the Cloneable interface will always make `clone()` fail. It says that implementing it is not a guarantee that `clone()` will work. This is very different.

Answer (score 4):

In your case the method of `Object` is invoked, since every class inherits from the `java.lang.Object` class. This `clone()` implementation does merely a field-by-field copy.

`Cloneable` is a **marker interface**. A marker interface is an interface that has neither methods nor variables defined but is used to provide type information about objects at run-time.

By adding this marker interface to your class definition it is guaranteed, that no `CloneNotSupportedException` will be ever thrown by invoking `clone` on your class.

---

A general advise is to take a look into [Copy Constructor versus Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) (Josh Bloch) whether you really want to use `clone` at all.

Answer (score 3):

The root class `java.lang.Object` contains the method [clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29). By default, if the concrete class implements Cloneable, the default class implementation makes a shallow copy.

From the method documentation:

> The method clone for class Object performs a specific cloning
>   operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the
>   interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown.  ...
>   Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a
>   "deep copy" operation.